# Do you need done in jasmine in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

Say I have the following code

```
it('should do something', () => {
  someObservable.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
     expect(someResult).toEqual(someValue);
     // done(); here ? 
  });
});
```

What I am wondering is, is the `done` callback needed in the subscribe when `take` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So why `done()` is used, `done()` is used when you have the some asynchronous element in the test, could be an API call which you expect to give you result in some time in future for example

```
 it('some test', ()=>{
    
    // do some stuff like click on a button
    
   // using settimeout because I am expecting my async work will be done after sometime 
    settimeout(()=> {
      // write your assert here.
    }, 2000)
  })
```

Above test will pass but the actual testing will not be done because after 2000 milliseconds there where be no test running as the execution gets over and you might get some error in the browser console.

So to handle this situation we use `done()`. It tells to Jasmine that the test is still not over and wait for all for `done()` callback to be executed.

Now coming back to your question do we need `done()` in case of `take(1)` it completely depends on the what observable is doing if its not mocked and you are expecting this to return data after a while like 1-5 seconds then you must use the `done()`.

If its mocked like an API call then you don't need this you can use the following as well

```
it('should do something', () => {
  const subscribedFired = false;
  someObservable.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
     expect(someResult).toEqual(someValue);
     subscribedFired = true;
  });

  expect(subscribedFired ).toEqual(true);
});
```

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to use done even if you are using take(1) . The reason is that your code is still executing asynchronously, and done is the way you tell the test that we are no longer waiting for more asynchronous code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The `done`-function only mark this `it` as done for jasmine. It has nothing to do with observalbe handling.

Sidenode: This test might fail. The `done` function has to be passed as parameter.

Comment: yes but do I need it in this case, if I already use `take` that should end the stream and therefore the test should end. The done as a callback for asynchronous work. see https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async#callbacks